# jsp Ajax GET working POST not working

Tags: ajax, jsp, tomcat6

I need to refresh some part of the browser. Hence I am using Ajax. When I use GET method, I can see the data at the server, but when I use POST i am not able to.
Any pointers please ?

-----------Code for searchPan.jsp-------------------------

```
<html>
  <%
  try
  {
          System.out.println("url is " + request.getRequestURI());
          System.out.println("pan is " + request.getQueryString());
          System.out.println("pan is " + request.getParameter("pan"));
  }
  catch(Exception E)
  {
          System.out.println("Error happened " + E);
  }
          //promo_card cardobj = new promo_card();
          //out.println(cardobj.getData());
  %>
</html>
```

---

----------------------------code for GET------------------------------------

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
 if(xmlhttp.readyState==0)
         document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='Uninitialized';
 else if(xmlhttp.readyState==1)
         document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='Loading...';
 else if(xmlhttp.readyState==2)
         document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='Loaded';
 else if(xmlhttp.readyState==3)
         document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='Interactive';
 else if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.readyState == 200)
         document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
if(xmlhttp)
{
  var queryString = 'searchPan.jsp?pan=' + document.getElementById('pan_number').value;
  xmlhttp.open("GET", queryString, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

### When I use GET method, I get the below output

```
url is /cardsit/promo/card/searchPan.jsp
pan is pan=123456789
pan is 123456789
```

---

```
When I use POST, I am unable, .. as below.
url is /cardsit/promo/card/searchPan.jsp
pan is null
pan is null
```

---

----------------------code for POST----------------------------

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "searchPan.jsp", true);
  var queryString = 'searchPan.jsp';
  queryString = 'pan=' + document.getElementById('pan_number').value;
  alert(queryString);
  xmlhttp.send(queryString);
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below code

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "searchPan.jsp", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var queryString = 'pan=' + document.getElementById('pan_number').value;
xmlhttp.send(queryString);
```

Comment: wow.. that worked. 
url is /cardsit/promo/card/searchPan.jsp 
pan is null 
pan is 123456789

Answer (score 1):

Add this line, it helped me last time.

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```